# How to stack cards for Solitaire?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Trying to do this project on my own running into some slight issues.    I have decided to cut the card with overflow so that I can stack but the stack isn't exactly working. The goal is to get the cards to stack together more. I have attached a picture along with code for the css portion and code for the react portion, I pretty much use that same code in a component and call that component seven times to get all 7 columns.  I have the functionality that loads the cards into the game. I have also included details concerning the steps I have tried from other articles that were similar to my question.  [image: Here is what it currently looks like]

Here is my css code :

```
    body {
  background: #339900; 
}

.container {
  width: 1700px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
span {
  display: block; 
}

.outline {
  text-align: center; 
  background: #FFF; 
  color: #cc0033; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
}
.scene {
  width: 120px; 
  height: 180px; 
  perspective: 360px; 
}

.top{ 
  text-align: left;
}
.bottom{ 
  text-align: right;
}

.topRow{
  display: flex;
}

.drawPile {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 300px;
  width: 500px;

}
.finalStack {
  width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.bottomRow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.drawFrom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:  center;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  background: blue;
}

.black {
  color: black;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.deck {
  display: flex; 
  height: 200px; 
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
  flex: 100px 1 0; 
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  background-color: white; 
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px gray; 
  width: 120px;
  height: 180px; 

}

.stackedCards {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lastInStack {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Not sure if this is needed but I will post the code for each section. I am doing this in react.

```
render() {
    console.log("BottomSection");
    console.log(this.props);
    const cards = this.props.cards;
    console.log(cards);
    return (
      <div>
        {cards.map((card, id) => (
            <div  key = {id} className="deck">
                <div onClick = {this.clickingCard} draggable = "true" className = { id === this.props.cards.length -1 ? "card lastInStack outline scene column" : "card stackedCards outline scene column"}>
                <div className={"top " + card.color}>
                <span>{card.value}</span>{" "}
                {card.suit === "hearts" ? (
                  <span>&hearts;</span>
                ) : card.suit === "spades" ? (
                  <span>&spades;</span>
                ) : card.suit === "clubs" ? (
                  <span>&clubs;</span>
                ) : (
                  <span>&#x2666;</span>
                )}
              </div>
              {card.suit === "hearts" ? (
                <h1 className={card.color}>&hearts;</h1>
              ) : card.suit === "spades" ? (
                <h1 className={card.color}>&spades;</h1>
              ) : card.suit === "clubs" ? (
                <h1 className={card.color}>&clubs;</h1>
              ) : (
                <h1 className={card.color}>&#x2666;</h1>
              )}
              <div className={"bottom " + card.color}>
                {card.suit === "hearts" ? (
                  <span>&hearts;</span>
                ) : card.suit === "spades" ? (
                  <span>&spades;</span>
                ) : card.suit === "clubs" ? (
                  <span>&clubs;</span>
                ) : (
                  <span>&#x2666;</span>
                )}
                <span>{card.value}</span>
                {/* <hr/> */}
              </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Okay, so the idea here is to stack the cards up so that they are connected with no green space between the cards. I will have to turn the cards over or have a back side but right now I am just trying to stack the cards. I will worry about the backside and clicking a card to reveal its other side once I actually get everything to stack up correctly.  I have tried to use margin-bottom at a negative amount however this seems to only stretch the card itself and make it longer. Not sure if this is because of the way I am creating each individual card instead of using images.  I also tried using negative top and position relative as one of the articles recommended but didn't see a change. The other articles didn't seem to apply to my implementation.

Comment: You may find your answer **[here](https://madewithreact.com/solitaire-game/)**

Comment: Hello! Please provide and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Full code is at https://github.com/codejoncode/solitaireReact   I provided examples what I tried and the code relevant to what I am doing.  You either can help or you can't.   None of the other parts has anything to do with why it's not stacking.

Comment: I know it is a big work, but you may rewrite the components in svg. The svg tags are supported in react. Svg is just made for this kind of task.

Comment: And by the way I just found the import feature of codesandbox today. I tried it out on your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/github/codejoncode/solitaireReact/tree/master/client

Comment: wow Peter how do you import to codesandbox it is nice to have provided this. Looks like you figured it out though  I just tried the deck height removal before seeing your comment. I appreciate you looking into this. I really appreciate it.  Is there a tutorial or video for the codesandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.deck {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}
.lastInstack {
  /*leave blank no need for overflow*/
}
```

This is the solution to the way I implemented the code. The changes were looked into by Peter Ambruzs as well. The reason why it was not working is that of the height set on deck it separated each div by the height.  Removing the height removes the separation.